# Remove field from file using commands like awk, sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I need to remove the timezone section from the timestamp using awk.

**File entry:**

```
2015-09-30 07:01:33,979 test1
```

**Expected output:**

```
2015-09-30 07:01:33 test1
```

Comment: not sure, why the question is down marked.

Comment: Because you didn't post what you have tried so far as requested by @dda. Note the upvotes his comment received while your question was receiving downvotes. Had you done that you would have received other, possible better, answers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "2015-09-30 07:01:33,979 test1" | awk -F"[ ,]" '{print $1,$2,$4}' 
2015-09-30 07:01:33 test1
```

or

```
$ echo "2015-09-30 07:01:33,979 test1" | awk '{sub(/,.* /," ")}1'
2015-09-30 07:01:33 test1
```